# Matlab Arrays of 2x2 matrices and element by element matrix/vector multiplication

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to have a time series of 2x2 complex matrices,Ot, and I then want to have 1-line commands to multiply an array of complex vectors Vt, by the array Ot where the position in the array is understood as the time instant.  I will want Vtprime(i) = Ot(i)*Vt(i).  Can anyone suggest a simple way to implement this?

Suppose I have  a matrix, M(t), where the elements m(j,k) are functions of t and t is an element of some series (t = 0:0.1:3).  Can I create an array of matrices very easily?

I understand how to have an array in Matlab, and even a two dimensional array, where each "i" index holds two complex numbers (j=0,1).  That would be a way to have a "time series of complex 2-d vectors".  A way to have a time series of complex matrices would be a three dimensional array. (i,j,k) denotes the "ith" matrix and j=0,1 and k=0,1 give the elements of that matrix.

If I go a head and treat matlab like a programming language with no special packages, then I end up having to write the matrix multiplications in terms of loops etc.  This then goes towards all the matrix operations.  I would prefer to use commands that will make all this very easy if I can.

Comment: The problem is very unclear. What is dimensions of Ot? Is it a **cell array** of 2x2 matrices? What is class and dimensions of Vt and of each element of Vt?

Comment: Could you please pose a question at a time, and be specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved with Matlab array iterations like

```
vtprime(:) = Ot(:)*Vt(:)
```

if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: if you don't understand comment, don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ot and Vt are both changing with time index, I think the best way to do this is in a loop.  (If only one of Ot or Vt was changing with time, you could set it up in one big matrix multiplication.)

Here's how I would set it up:  Ot is a complex 2x2xI 3D matrix, so that

```
Ot(:,:,i)
```

references the matrix at time instant i.

Vt is a complex 2xI matrix, so that

```
Vt(:,i)
```

references the vector at time instant i.

To do the multiplication:

```
for i = 1:I
    Vtprime(:,i) = Ot(:,:,i) * Vt(:,i);
end
```

The resulting Vtprime is a 2xI matrix set up so that `Vtprime(:,i)` is the output at time instant i.